# The accuracy from left to right and that from right to left of the floating point arithmetic sums

Tags: numerical-methods

> **Question 1** Show that floating point arithmetic sums
>   $$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2} = 1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\dotsb+\frac{1}{n^2}$$
>   with accuracy $\mathcal O(n)\epsilon$ from left to right, while summing from right to left gives accuracy $\mathcal O(\log n)\epsilon$.

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HtoI.png)

There is an example of summing 5, 10, 15
$\left(\left(5+10\right)\left(1+\epsilon\right)+15\right)\left(1+\epsilon\right) =30+45\epsilon$
$\left(\left(15+10\right)\left(1+\epsilon\right)+5\right)\left(1+\epsilon\right)  = 30+55\epsilon$

Where does the form $\left(1+\epsilon\right)$ come from? And any suggestion on how to approach this problem? thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You get it from
$$
fl(a+b)=(a+b)(1+\delta)
$$
with $|δ|\leϵ$ the quasi random relative error of the floating point execution of the operation.

---

In computing $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ via the partial sums $s_{m+1}=s_m+a_{m+1}$ each numerical step produces an error $Δs_m$ that accumulates as
$$
s_{m+1}+Δs_{m+1}=fl(s_m+Δs_m+a_{m+1})=(s_m+Δs_m+a_{m+1})(1+\delta_m)
$$
The errors are dominated by the first order terms, so that up to higher order terms after removing the exact terms one gets
$$
Δs_{m+1}=Δs_m+s_{m+1}\delta_m
$$
So in first order of approximation, the last error added to the sum is proportional to the sum up to date, which in total gives 
$$
Δs_n=s_2\delta_1+s_3\delta_2+…+s_n\delta_{n-1}.
$$

The quasi random quantities $\delta_m$ are bound by a machine constant $ϵ$. The partial sums have the absolute sums as upper bound. Combining both one gets
$$
|Δs_n|\le \sum_{k=1}^n (n+1-k)·|a_k|\,·\,ϵ
$$

---

For the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}$ summing from the front gives $a_k=\frac1{k^2}$ and the first order coefficient of the error term $$
\sum_{k=1}^n (n+1-k)·|a_k|=(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\le(n+1)\frac{\pi^2}6-\ln(n+1)=O(n)
$$

---

Summing from the end is encoded as $a_k=\frac1{(n+1-k)^2}$ which gives the first order coefficient of the error term as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+1-k}\le 1+\ln(n)=O(\log n)
$$

---

---

The identities used are
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6 
$$
and, as an easy consequence of $e^x\ge 1+x$ or bounds on $\int_{k-1}^k\frac1x\,dx$,
$$
\ln(k+1)-\ln(k)\le \frac1k\le \ln(k)-\ln(k-1)\\
\ln(n+1)-\ln(1)\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\le 1+\ln(n)-\ln(1)
$$

Comment: Does p represent the portion of the error and the sum? But why we add $1/(p^2)$ all the way to $1/n^2$? If we add from right to left, isn't the first term $1/n^2$?

Comment: The first summation is $\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{(n-1)^2}$. I assumed that the question is only about the error of the summation, not the computation of the terms. The error formula for the last 3 terms is $((a_n+a_{n-1})(1+δ_{n-1})+a_{n-2})(1+δ_{n-2})$ etc., so that the coefficient for $δ_p$ is $a_n+a_{n-1}+…+a_p$.

Comment: Isn't the coefficient of $\delta_{n-2}$ is $\left(a_n+a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+\left(a_n+a_{n-1}\right)\delta_{n-1}\right)$? Or are you saying we can ignore $\left(a_n+a_{n-})\right)\delta_{n-1}$ this part somehow?

Comment: Yes, ignore. For error estimates, one is only interested in the first order terms, as one has to add a lot of size $\mu^2$ terms to get a contribution of magnitude $\mu$, as $\mu=2^{-53}<10^{-15}$.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, when you were summing the error, you ignored the part $-(1/n)$, why is that? And can i just say that $1/p$ is the error for $\delta_p$?

Comment: Because in the end, one is interested in an upper bound. One could take them into consideration to get $(\ln(n)-1)ϵ$ as upper bound, but that is still $O(ln(n)⋅ϵ)$.

Comment: And we can just say that $O\left(ln\left(n\right)\cdot\epsilon\right)$ = $O\left(log\left(n\right)\cdot\epsilon\right)$?

Comment: Yes. Because the difference between $\ln x$ and $\log_c(x)=\ln(x)/\ln(c)$ is a constant factor.

Comment: Changed/updated the hints to a full and coherent answer.